# How to add elevation to a buffer polygon in geopandas

Tags: geopandas

How would I add a zero elevation value to each xy component of a buffer polygon, i.e.

```
Transform POLYGON ((0.20000 0.00000, 0.19904 -0.01960, ...)) into POLYGON ((0.20000 0.00000 0, 0.19904 -0.01960 0, ...))
```

[image]

Comment: your question is not clear as code sample is an image not marked up text and what you want has ellipses...  fundamentally shapely support 2D geometry, not 3D and geopandas uses Shapley for geometry

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking how you can add a third dimension to your shapely objects and have them set to zero by default.

Here's a way to do so:

```py
import shapely.ops

def add_zero_z(geom):
    def _add_zero_z(x, y):
        return x, y, [0 for _ in x]
    return shapely.ops.transform(_add_zero_z, geom)
```

Here's an example of how to use it:

```py
import shapely.geometry

x_2D = shapely.geometry.Point((0,0))
print(x_2D.wkt)
# POINT (0 0)

x_3D = add_zero_z(x_2D)
print(x_3D.wkt)
# POINT (0 0 0)
```

You can also apply the function to a whole GeoDataFrame:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id':[1,2],
                        'geometry':[shapely.geometry.Point((0,0)),
                                    shapely.geometry.Point((1,1))]},
                       geometry='geometry')

# Applying the function to the "geometry" column and replacing it
gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda geom: add_zero_z(geom))

print(gdf)
#    id                           geometry
# 0   1  POINT Z (0.00000 0.00000 0.00000)
# 1   2  POINT Z (1.00000 1.00000 0.00000)
```

### Credit

My idea for this answer came from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/415879/123828) by user [mikewatt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/64255/mikewatt).